# Passing params to update columns with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This code creates new Models just fine, but when it should update a model, it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
if Model.exists?(:s => params[:s], :img => params[:image]) do
  @update = Model.where(:s => params[:s], :img => params[:image])
  @update.update_all({num: params[:num], url: params[url].values[0]})
  @update.save
end
else
  @model = Model.new(s: params[:s], img: params[:image], num: params[:num], url: params[url].values[0])
  @model.save
end
```

Comment: Does removing the `@update.save` help?

Comment: @bumpy removing `@update.save` doesn't change anything.

Comment: there are couple of mistakes i see, you dont need `do` with `if` . then secondly you cant call `.update` with array/active relation i.e `@update`, then if you are using if and else why are you having end after `if` condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Model.exists?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) doesn't take a block but you're giving it one. That means that your code is equivalent to:

```
if Model.exists?(:s => params[:s], :img => params[:image])
else
  @model = Model.new(s: params[:s], img: params[:image], num: params[:num], url: params[url].values[0])
  @model.save
end
```

so of course the update never happens. Your block really should be the `if`'s body. Also, `update_all` directly updates the database so there's no need to call `@update.save` (which will fail anyway since `@update` is a relation rather than a model instance):

```
if Model.exists?(:s => params[:s], :img => params[:image])
  @update = Model.where(:s => params[:s], :img => params[:image])
  @update.update_all({num: params[:num], url: params[url].values[0]})
else
  @model = Model.new(s: params[:s], img: params[:image], num: params[:num], url: params[url].values[0])
  @model.save
end
```

Thanks [Athar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089231/athar) for the reminder about `save`.

Comment: dont you think it will crash with `@update.save` bcoz @update is `ActiveRecord::Relation`

Comment: Thanks, as @Athar said it did crash with `@update.save`. But, after removing that, it worked!